# Selecting multiple icons in Finder using the keyboard?

Tags: finder, keyboard

Is there a way to select icons (using the keyboard) that aren't directly touching? In Windows, I'd press `Ctrl`+`Down`, but it doesn't work in the Finder view. I've tried all the usual keyboard shortcuts, but it doesn't seem to work. I can multi-select other icons just fine, but I can't multi-select these two.

The picture explains it better than I could. The icons in this folder are aligned to the grid.

[image: finder view]

Comment: Since it is not working as I expected it, I have deleted my answer ^^

Comment: `Shift + down` should work. It does for me. Can you check and confirm?

Comment: Apparently it works only if the view is not sorted. See my answer.

Comment: Have you tried shift + right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is fairly unintuitive.

1. Select the last item (the PSD).
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>.
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Right</kbd> repeatedly until you get the selection you want.

Comment: That doesn't work in Sierra 10.12.6. Using spreadsheet coordinates, If I select `A2`, then pressing shift+up will select `A1`. Then pressing shift+right will select `B2, C2, D2`. You end up with an "L" shape.

Answer (score 2):

You could use <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to change to the list view and then just use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I thought <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> should work. I tried and the results were, let us say, special:

When your view is sorted by Name, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> does not go the last item.

If your view is not sorted, (Sort By: None), then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> selecs the last item as well.

See this [screencast](http://youtu.be/g1aXamtiOuI). (This is my first screencast, so not a very good one)

Comment: I tested with Sort By: None as well as Name in Sierra 10.12.6. Neither works.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting multiple icons with the keyboard in Finder's Icons View is very limited. Here's a few options:

`cmd`+`click`: This definitely works in Icons View, but you have to use the mouse to click.

`shift`+`arrows`: This only works properly in a single row or a single column. If you start trying to use the arrow keys to select more than a single row or column, you'll get inconsistent and strange results.

The only real solution, unfortunately, is to switch to List View to do the multiple selection.

Some people mentioned that Icons View keyboard selection works when not sorted, but my testing on Sierra 10.12.6 found that it didn't matter whether Icons View was sorted or not, keyboard selection didn't work beyond a single row/column.