# OSX Finder: Select multiple discrete files/items using keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, windows

Let's say I have got a bunch of items in a folder on my Finder. And I want to make a non-continuous selection.
I can do that using my trackpad and <kbd>CMD</kbd> + *click* as in this answer: [How do you select multiple specific files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82780/how-do-you-select-multiple-specific-files)

But I don't want to use my trackpad (I am way faster using my keyboard). On Windows, you would hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, navigate using the <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys and select the desired items/files using <kbd>Space bar</kbd>

This is also unanswered on Apple Discussions: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3298378?start=0

Mind that [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51679/selecting-multiple-icons-in-finder-using-the-keyboard) doesn't answer as it has two continuous items albeit on different lines.

Comment: I am looking for a script or automation for this same action